# Unknown anime with a tiny boy flying on a goose and a giant man who doesn't have a reflection in the water

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to find an interesting anime from my childhood. I don't know if this portion I've seen (I don't remember the whole thing) is from an animated film or series. I remember that the art style was reminiscent of *Arupusu no sho-jo Haiji* (アルプスの少女ハイジ) (informally known as *Heidi, Girl of the Alps*) and most Studio Ghibli films — its setting is in the country, as far as I can remember.

All I can remember is a small boy somehow flying on a goose (I don't remember whether the boy was small or the goose was giant) and eventually arriving to a house in which a creepy giant bearded man lived. Then, the boy discovered that the man doesn't have a reflection in the water, and that he is a ghost. That's all I can remember. I suspect that the series originated in the 90s.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Sounds a bit like an anime version of *Jack and the Beanstalk*. If this hasn't been answered by the time I get home then I'll have a look myself.

Comment: @F1Krazy Thank you for your suggestion, but that's not it. *Jack and the Beanstalk* was also one of the anime I have watched in my childhood. I've recently rediscovered and rewatched it. No geese anywhere, and the giant doesn't have a beard. Plus, the style is nothing like that of *Heidi*.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[That sounds very much like Nils Holgersson.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Adventures_of_Nils_(anime))

It has the tiny boy on a goose.

It is mostly in rural settings.

The drawing style resembles the Heidi cartoons.

I don't know about the old man and the reflection.  I've never watched Nils.  I see commercials for it sometimes on TV here in Germany.

Picture from Wikipedia:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you, I can't believe that after so many years, I finally get to watch it again!

Comment: That one was incredibly obvious to me. I was just a bit late. Although I would think it pretty distinct from Miyazaki's style. The book by Selma Lagerlöf is readable, too, although the supporting characters are richer in the series. By the way, the soundtrack by Karel Svoboda is one of the best ever made. That guy had the nickname 'the Czech Mozart'. I understand why ( :

Comment: The book was, as I recall, originally written to be a schoolbook in Swedish geography. Nils Holgersson and his goose also appeared on the reverse of the previous run of the swedish [20kr bill](https://www.leftovercurrency.com/exchange/swedish-kronor/withdrawn-swedish-krona-banknotes/20-swedish-kronor-banknote-selma-lagerlof), with Selma Lagerlöf on the front.

Comment: @Arthur Yes it was. Lagerlöf was a smart woman and a famous one. It doesn't surprise me that school hasn't picked up on the idea that education might be presented in a fun or captivating way.